# Can a function be a Python dataclass member?

Tags: python, types

I'm trying to keep some functions together and tried a Python dataclass for this. I could not come up with or find how to assign a type to a function within a dataclass.

In example below I used a dummy type `int`, but what I should use correctly instead of `int`?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

inc = lambda x : x+1

@dataclass
class Holder:
  func: int # but I need a better type signature here

h = Holder(inc)

assert h.func(1) == 2
```

Comment: ... and the  -1 goes exactly for... "You should have known it before"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use the [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) type

```
from typing import Callable

@dataclass
class Holder:
  func: Callable[[int], int]
```

Comment: should it be `Callable[int, int]`?

Comment: The argument section is supposed to be a list hence `[int]`

Comment: not sure why - `inc` accepts just an `int`, not a list of `int`

Comment: oh, it is something `Callable` wants!

Comment: Not your function, but functions in general might have more than one argument, that's why the argument section of the type hint is enclosed in `[]`